# I can't find the wrong code on line 23

Tags: php

I can't find the wrong code on line 23.

```
<html>
<head><title>cw5</title></head>
<body> 
<form method=post>
Please enter 2 numbers: <br>
The first number: <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
The second number: <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form><hr>
<?php 
   $num=$_POST["num1"]+$_POST["num2"];
   echo $_POST['num1']."+".$_POST['num2']."=".$num."<br>";

   $num2=$_POST["num1"]-$_POST["num2"];
   echo $_POST['num1']."-".$_POST['num2']."=" .$num2."<br>";

   $num3=$_POST["num1"]*$_POST["num2"];
   echo $_POST['num1']."x".$_POST['num2']."=" .$num3."<br>";

   $num4=$_POST["num1"]/$_POST["num2"];
   echo $_POST['num1']."/".$_POST['num2']."=" .$num4."<br>";

   $num5=$_POST["num1"]%$_POST["num2"];
   **echo "the remains of" $_POST['num1']."/".$_POST['num2']. "is".$num5."<br>";**
?>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First, I suggest telling us which line is 23 so we don't have to count. :) Oops, I see it's the one with the asterisks now :(

Comment: You should *always* post the actual text of the error message!

Comment: I counted 23 rows and found `**echo` is the wrong code lol :)

Comment: You have no doctype specified. Not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a `.` between `"the remains of"` and `$_POST['num1']`

Answer (score 0):

Several minor syntax errors

- Missing several "
- Misplaced .

Here is the full code:

```
<html>
<head><title>cw5</title></head>
<body> 
<form method=post>
Please enter 2 numbers: <br>
The first number: <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
The second number: <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form><hr>
<?php 
   $num=$_POST["num1"]+$_POST["num2"];
   echo $_POST['num1']."+".$_POST['num2']."=" .$num. "<br>";

   $num2=$_POST["num1"]-$_POST["num2"];
   echo $_POST['num1']."-".$_POST['num2']."=" .$num2. "<br>";

   $num3=$_POST["num1"]*$_POST["num2"];
   echo $_POST['num1']."x".$_POST['num2']."=" .$num3. "<br>";

   $num4=$_POST["num1"]/$_POST["num2"];
   echo $_POST['num1']."/".$_POST['num2']."=" .$num4. "<br>";

   $num5=$_POST["num1"]%$_POST["num2"];
   echo "the remains of " . $_POST['num1']."/".$_POST['num2']." is " .$num5;
?>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @edo, Great! If this answers your question, click the check mark at the upper-left of this answer. That marks your question as answered so that it is removed from the unanswered questions list.